# Shell script to remove a string from .gz file

Tags: unix

I want to remove a string value(lk=1&) from a .gz file. I tried with the below command and got the error. Can some one help me to fix this out?

**command:**
sed -e '/lk=1&/' sample_0001.gz

**Error:**
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: missing command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sed: -e expression #1, char 7: missing command

As the error message says it, a command is missing in the `/lk=1&/` expression. I think you wanted to do this:

```
sed -e 's/lk=1&//g' sample_0001.gz
```

But this won't work either, because the file seems to be zipped. You need to unzip first, do the replacement and zip it back again, for example like this:

```
gunzip sample_0001.gz
sed -i -e 's/lk=1&//g' sample_0001
gzip sample_0001
```

If you don't want to update the zip, just show the contents and replace the string and print the result, then:

```
zcat sample_0001.gz | sed -e 's/lk=1&//g'
```

Comment: Thanks this one helps me to get it right.zcat sample_0001.gz | sed -e 's/lk=1&//g'